# How to show sub categories in category page in magento?

Tags: magento2, category

How to show sub categories in category page in magento 2.0?

Comment: checkout this url https://github.com/pratikmage/magento2_subcategory may be help you

Comment: Should add that module in magento? @Pratik

Comment: I am getting error '
Notice: Undefined variable: collectionFactory'  after enabling the your module.

Comment: issue has been resolve pls check.

Comment: Yes that issue has gone but the subcategory product are not showing.

Comment: The sub categories are showing in facets area and all products which are displayed are right now not visible.  Actually i wanted to show like this URL     http://www.tolexo.com/safety/gloves-and-hand-protection.html

Comment: Thank you very much... It works for me. but you aligment is not proper.  How to accept answer?

Comment: Hi @Pratik , have you worked on UI part of it?